# Caching in SSRS before clicking View Report

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

I know that there is Sql Server Reporting Services uses caching.  But, I would like to now if it caches the report before clicking the View Report button i.e. does it already cache the data for the report by merely changing the values of the dropdown Report Parameters.  Here is the scenario:

1. I call stored procedures to get the labels and values of the dropdown report parameters aside form the main report itself.
2. My dropdown is cascading i.e. There are three dropdown lists (from top to bottom) say Dropdown A, B and C.  The labels and values of Dropdown C are dependent on Dropdown B.  Dropdown B is dependent on Dropdown A.
3. I use SQL Server 2005 version as Report Server, tables and stored procedures.  If its an exclusive feature of 2008, I would be glad to know, but please indicate the version you are explaining.

Any relevant information is appreciated.  Thank you in advance for your time and expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A report is cached with combination of parameters -- different parameter combinations result in different cache instances of the report.

Caching happens the "first time" a report is **generated**, after the previous version expired.

If you want to pre-load the cache to speed-up "the first delivery", use the **Null Provider** for the method of delivery in a data-driven subscription.

To address your problem -- does changing a drop-down box re-run a report? On my server I have to click the [View Report] button to start generating the report -- the report is not cached until you see "*Report is being generated*" message.